# How to interpret “pouvais toujours” here?

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical, adverbes, imparfait

> {I said}: Pour vous faire passer une radio, rendez-vous à la salle là-bas.
>
> {A patient said}: Ah, c’était donc bien par là. Je ***pouvais toujours*** chercher à un autre étage ! Merci.

I've never heard the Imparfait “pouvais”  used like this before, so it pulled me up short.

Comment: The [original question](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/26559/revisions) was different "Can you use the Imparfait « je pouvais » for the conditional meaning « je pourrais » or « j'aurais pu »?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non. Le mot *toujours* a un sens particulier ici. Il ne signifie pas « *still* ». Il indique que l'action a peu de chances de réussir, voire aucune chance.

Il y a quelques formes courantes, mais potentiellement ce sens peut être utilisé à n'importe quel personne et n'importe quel temps.

- Tu peux toujours [faire …] = Tu peux [faire …] mais ça ne marchera sûrement pas.
- Je pouvais toujours [faire …] = Ça n'a servi à rien que je [fasse …].

Plus précisément, c'est le succès du but recherché qui est improbable ou impossible. L'improbabilité est connue au moment où la personne parle, pas au moment de l'action : dans une phrase au passé, on ne savait pas forcément que la tentative allait échouer au moment de faire cette tentative.

Exemples :

> Tu peux toujours essayer.   (*You can try.* — in a tone that implies *but I think it won't work*.)
>   Cause toujours.   (*Talk to the hand.* — you can talk to me but it won't do any good, you won't be able to get what you want.)
>   Cherche toujours, on ne sait jamais.   (*Do search, just in case, you never know.* — You aren't likely to find what you're looking for, but it isn't impossible, so you should try searching.)
>   Je pouvais toujours chercher.   (*It was futile for me to search, I didn't have a chance of finding it.*)

Comment: Hi. I have no problem understanding your first three examples, seeing "toujours" as "quand même", but I can't seem to wrap my head around the meaning/function of "pouvais" in this instance. I'm afraid I'm still none the wiser...

Comment: @Alone-zee *Quand même* is sort of related but it's different. I've expanded the explanations, does it help?

Comment: I wonder if this is a witty, self-mocking remark: "Thanks. I **was able to** look for it in the wrong place for nothing, **anyway**!"

Comment: Désolé, pas très d'accord avec *tu peux toujours* qui supposerait que ça ne va pas marcher. Ceci peut aussi vouloir dire *ca marche à tous les coups*: "si tu veux le faire taire, tu peux toujours le tuer". Ce n'est pas forcément une blague. Juste une gentille conversation entre tueurs. Non ?

Answer (score 4):

**This is not an answer to the question as it stands now but an answer to [the original question](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/26559/3) before the title was changed and  all hints to the conditional in the question removed.**

---

Non, on ne peut pas exprimer un conditionnel par un imparfait mais il n'y a aucune idée de conditionnel dans la phrase dite par le patient.

- > C’était donc bien par là. Je pouvais toujours chercher à un autre étage.<sup>1</sup>

  → Il n'y a aucune formulation d'hypothèse, mais l'expression de deux **faits réels** :

  - « C'était donc bien là  » : maintenant je suis au bon endroit,
  - « Je pouvais toujours chercher à un autre étage. » je cherchais au mauvais endroit, ce qui est un fait réel, avec un sous-entendu contenu dans l'adverbe *toujours* :« ça ne servait à rien. »
    Cet emploi non temporel de *toujours* est appelé « pragmatique » par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/toujours) (II, A) :

    > notamment avec l’auxiliaire pouvoir. Marque l'idée que ce qui est envisagé n'aura, en tout état de cause, aucune sorte d'effet; (*Tu peux toujours courir*.)

  [Cet article](http://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2004-2-page-39.htm) sur la polysémie de l'adverbe toujours qualifie cet emploi de « pouvoir toujours + infinitif » de « modal ». <sup>2</sup>

---

- > Si vous ne m'aviez pas indiqué la bonne direction je serais encore en train de chercher.

  → On exprime une condition qui ne s'est pas réalisée.

La condition est exprimée au  plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif (si vous ne m'aviez pas indiqué la bonne direction) avec une conséquence non réalisée  (je serais encore en train de chercher) au conditionnel présent.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The sentence must be understood as "So that was the place. It was useless looking on a different floor".</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Mosegaard Hansen, Maj-Britt. « La polysémie de l'adverbe toujours », *Travaux de linguistique*, vol. no49, no. 2, 2004, pp. 39-55.</sub>

Comment: Hi. Interesting, indeed. I've heard several hundreds of thousands of French sentences ever since I started learning French a year ago, but this is the first time that I've come across such use of "pouvais toujours". So how to interpret it is beyond me, I'm afraid. How does this sentence compare to: "Et moi qui cherchais à un autre étage.", for instance?

Comment: @Alone-zee I was editing the question while you were writing your comment, and I was precisely adding about that because i suspected it might be the cause of your misunderstanding. The academic article I'm pointing to is quite interesting.  It is quite academic with a lot of specific jargon. I suppose the sentence you are giving is quite close to it.